# skimage - TypeError: peak_local_max() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_peaks_per_label'

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

The following code gives me the error present in the title :

```
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
local_maxi = peak_local_max(imd,labels=iml, 
                            indices=False,num_peaks_per_label=2)
```

Where `imd` is a "distance transformed image" which was obtained with :

```
from scipy import ndimage
imd = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(im)
```

`im` is the input binary image that I would like to later on segment with the watershed function of scikit-image. But to use this function properly, I first need to find the markers which will serve as the starting flooding points : that's what I'm trying to do with the 'peak_local_max' function.

Also, `iml` is the labeled version of `im`, that I got with :

```
from skimage.measure import label
iml = label(im)
```

I don't know what I've been doing wrong. Also, I've noticed that, the function seems to totally ignore its `num_peaks` argument. For instance, when I do :

```
local_maxi = peak_local_max(imd,labels=iml,
                            indices=True,num_peaks=1)
```

I always get the same number of peaks detected as when I set `num_peaks=500` or `num_peaks=np.inf`. What am I missing here please ?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the latest version of `skimage`? Seems like this keyword has been added recently. I suppose you're having a version that is not up-to-date with the latest version of the docs. Could you check which version you're running?

Comment: @ a_guest Hello, my version is 0.12.3 according to the Anaconda Navigator. I didn't install scikit-image manually. It seems like this is the same version as what is provided on the scikit-image website. However, they don't mention that the latest stable version is included in the Anaconda distribution as it is with Python(x,y) and the Enthought Python Distribution. I will try to install it manually, thank you for the advice.

Comment: @ a_guest Hi again. I tried to pip install the .whl file that they provide on the site but only got "Requirement already satisfied" lines in response. I guess my version is up to date ?

Comment: Comparing [v0.12.x](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/api/skimage.feature.html?highlight=feature#skimage.feature.peak_local_max) with [v0.13dev](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html?highlight=feature#skimage.feature.peak_local_max) reveals that `num_peaks_per_label` was added in v0.13. [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-image) only contains v0.12.3. You need to [build the latest development version](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html#running-the-development-version) manually.

Comment: @a_guest Thank you very much for your answers, I was just reading the wrong version of the documentation... After updating to the v0.13dev everything went right !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @a_guest pointed out, my version of `skimage` wasn't matching with the version of the documentation I was referring to. The `num_peaks_per_label` argument is currently only available in the v0.13dev version. Updating my version to the dev version also fixed my problem with the `num_peaks` argument.

Comment: you can verify this as the answer to your question!